# Inheriting instance variables in Actionscript

Tags: inheritance, actionscript

I create `class A` with fields:

```
public var button1:Button;
public var button2:Button;
```

`class B extends class A` and has just the field

```
public var button1:Button;
```

I create an object like this:

```
var but:A = new B();
```

and then I put this in code:

```
but.button1.someproperty = ...
```

Which button is really referred ? button1 is the button in class A or button1 in class B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding variables is not permitted. You cannot define a `public var button1:Button;` in `class B extends class A` , if `class A` already has a variable by that name. It should be a compilation error.

Excerpts from Adobe's tutorials :

> Properties that are declared with the var or const keywords are inherited but cannot be overridden. To override a property means to redefine the property in a subclass. The only type of property that can be overridden are methods—that is, properties declared with the function keyword. Although you cannot override an instance variable, you can achieve similar functionality by creating getter and setter methods for the instance variable and overriding the methods.

For more [read here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcd.html).

Comment: thanks!! probably in my case is permitted because i'm using flex too. but i'm not sure, i'm newbie !

Comment: It can never be your case my case , its Adobe's case . Read the documentation , you are bound to get compilation error !

Comment: ok! after some test I comprise your answer!! Ya I also read documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `but` is of the type `A` but holds an instance of the type `B` which is a subtype of `A` (and as such compatible with the variable). So in the end, it points at an instance of `B`; so your `button1` would be B’s.

Note that `B` also has a button1, as that one was defined in `A` (it still also belongs to `B` though).

In the end though, you cannot really do this as it’s not possible to override fields, so you could not define `button1` again in `B` (as it’s already defined in `A`). A better example to show the effect of extending a type would be something like this:

```
public class A
{
    public function test() : void
    {
        trace('test() in A!');
    }
}
public class B extends A
{
    public function test() : void
    {
        trace('test() in B!');
    }
}

var x:A = new B();
x.test();
```

Comment: The example you cited doesn't correspond to the question asked . The example holds true for method overriding but variable overriding is illegal in Actionscript .

Comment: @NoobUnChained Please read my third paragraph, I’m aware of that. I understood the question more as a general question on polymorphism with simply a bad example (due to invalid syntax) to point the problem out. Hence the better example which shows how overriding works.